# How to get respective LatLon from the result return from Places AutoComplete Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Places AutocompleteFragment to get Place name, Address and LatLng as below:

```
tvWhereDestination.setOnClickListener {

        // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
        val fields: List<Place.Field> = asList(
            Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG
        )


        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields
        ).setCountry("US")
            .build(this)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE_DESTINATION)
    }
```

**problem:**

I could not get the respective latitude and longitude out from the result return as below:

The result return:

val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data!!)

place.latLng.toString() will show:  lat/lng: (x.xxxxxxx,xxx.xxxxxxx)

i tried place.latLng!!latitude but it will show syntax error.

Has anyone able to get the respective lat/lng?

Update:
in gradle , I have added:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

But I still can not get the respective Lat and Lng from the Place.latLng

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the field names:

```
place.latLng.latitude
place.latLng.longitude
```

Comment: this wont work. I tried. I have this in my  above update

Comment: when these approaches are used. It will have red-line underneath. 1) use place.latLng.latitude-- it will show: only safe(?.) or Non-null-asserted(!!) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of Type LatLng?  2) use place.latLng!!latitude -- it will show unresolvedreference: latitude

Comment: Ah, ok - latLng could be null, so to do a safe call, update it to place.latLng?.latitude, and if you need to provide a value in case it is null, update it to place.latLng?.latitude ?: "" - which will set it to "" if it is null.

Comment: Just realised the last part of your comment - it may not work due to the unresolvedreference...